# How can I modify the url of the Superset welcome page?

Tags: python, apache-superset

I would like to know how I can modify the URL to the welcome page.
Currently it is /superset/welcome.

It is run into superset/views/core.py in a @expose('/welcome').

I know I can modify the code inside this @expose, but I want to redirect to another url.

So I want to find the line where there is:

welcome_page = /superset/welcome

Answer (score 2):

In superset's file structure, navigate to:

`superset/app.py`

There you  will find

```
class SupersetIndexView(IndexView):
    @expose("/")
    def index(self) -> FlaskResponse:
        return redirect("/superset/welcome")
```

Modify this to path where you want to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

As of Superset 1.3, you can change the default landing page by adding this code to your [Superset config](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset):

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect

from flask_appbuilder import expose, IndexView

from superset.typing import FlaskResponse

class SupersetDashboardIndexView(IndexView):
    @expose("/")
    def index(self) -> FlaskResponse:
        return redirect("/dashboard/list/")

FAB_INDEX_VIEW = f"{SupersetDashboardIndexView.__module__}.{SupersetDashboardIndexView.__name__}"
```

In the above example, I am using `/dashboard/list/` instead of the default `/superset/welcome/`.

The code above is [Unlicensed](https://spdx.org/licenses/Unlicense.html) and thus is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Improved code to select landing page based on user role name:
https://gist.github.com/d9k/a638071ce7146ef01c27779a51d96f2b

Comment: I am getting an error while using this lines - `NameError: name 'BaseView' is not defined
2022-06-26 10:52:36,770:ERROR:superset.app:Failed to create app`